# How can I find the size of a redis topic (subset of keys)?

Tags: redis, lua

My redis keys are ordered using all kind of topics (e.g. `Topic:SubTopic:Key`).

I would like to find the byte size of a section `Topic:*` or a `Topic:SubTopic:*`.

Beneath a topic I can have all kinds of entries (lists, strings, hashes, sets etc.).

Now I know the cli has the `memory usage <key>` command, but I'd like to somehow call this on the redis server using lua.

My approach was to run something like:

```
eval "local keys = redis.call('keys',KEYS[1]) ; local sum=0 ; for _,k in ipairs(keys) do sum = sum + redis.call('memory usage', k) end ; return sum" 1 Topic:SubTopic:*
```

*I know that this command has a performance impact, and therefore I'm going to run this offline just to analyze our data structures and not on production.*

My main problem is that I couldn't find a redis server command to find the memory usage of a key that is similar to the cli command.

Questions:

1. Is there a better approach to analyze my keys? Using `bigkeys` isn't enough.
2. If not, is there any equivalent memory usage command that I can run as part of a lua script to get the byte size of a key?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`MEMORY USAGE`](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage) to obtain the byte size including overheads of a given key and value.

Note: even if running offline, you should use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) instead of `KEYS` in your Lua script - this will reduce the script's runtime memory consumption and prevent the sandbox's stack from overflowing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for an equivalent call to memory usage that I can call using my lua script on redis...
Regarding the scan issue, I'm running on version 4.0.10 that has a bug with scan not returning all keys.